# How to create a county level map of USA and Puerto Rico for Highcharter

Tags: highcharts, maps, r-highcharter

Highcharts have map of US and its territories, as shown in this [link](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.11.0/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/mapdata/countries/us/custom/us-all-territories). I want my USA and Puerto Rico map to look like this. However, it is not in the county level.

```
map <- read_sf("app/data/georef-united-states-of-america-county.geojson")

usaprmap <- map %>% 
          filter(coty_area_code %in% c("USA","PRI"))

geojson_map <- sf_geojson(usaprmap)
```

I also have a geojson file of USA and its territories at the county level from this [website](https://public.opendatasoft.com/explore/dataset/us-county-boundaries/map/?disjunctive.statefp&disjunctive.countyfp&disjunctive.name&disjunctive.namelsad&disjunctive.stusab&disjunctive.state_name&location=5,17.03578,-73.34473&basemap=jawg.light), but it is set up as a globe, not the same set up as the above link.

I am new to highcharter and I am at a complete loss in the direction to go to. Is there a way to merge the two information together? Do I create a custom map?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Hi @Isa, So are you basically looking for a USA map at the county level? If so, please check the docs about Highcharts Map collection: https://www.highcharts.com/docs/maps/map-collection It seems that the map `United States of America, admin2` should meet your requirements. Live example: https://jsfiddle.net/ctsf1aLv/

Comment: Hello @ppotaczek, I want both USA and Puerto Rico on the map. The example you showed did not have Puerto Rico.

Comment: In this case, you will need to create a custom map by modifying some existing one. Please check this article: https://www.highcharts.com/docs/maps/custom-geojson-maps which presents step-by-step how you can do that.